# How to show selected checked TableViewCell in IOS(Objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi friends I am new in IOS. I am creating a table view of state list. On button click I'm showing a TableView on popup. Code for creating state list is

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
selectedState = [NSMutableArray new];
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth-50, screenHeight-50)];
mytableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth-50, screenHeight-100)];
mytableview.delegate =self;
mytableview.dataSource=self;
[contentView addSubview:mytableview];
UIButton *save = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenHeight-100, screenWidth-50, 50)];
[save setTitle:@"SAVE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
save.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
[save setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[save addTarget:self action:@selector(saveActionForState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[save setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:41.0/255.0 green:178.0/255.0 blue:165.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[contentView addSubview:save];

[[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentView:contentView andAnimated:YES];
```

For table creation code is

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return [stateList count];

}

      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
static NSString *CRTableViewCellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
if(selectStateButton ==1){

        CRTableViewCell *cell = (CRTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CRTableViewCellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CRTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CRTableViewCellIdentifier];
        }


        NSString *text = [stateList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        cell.isSelected = [selectedState containsObject:text] ? YES : NO;
        cell.textLabel.text = text;




        return cell;
 }
 }
```

On selection of table cell checked the cell of IOS.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
if(selectStateButton ==1){
    //[selectedStatesForSelect2 removeAllObjects];
NSString *text = [stateList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSInteger indexings = [indexPath row]+1;

if ([selectedState containsObject:text]){
    [selectedState removeObject:text];
    [selectedStatesId removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexings]];
 }else{
     //NSLog(@"count%lu indexing %@",(unsigned long)[selectedState count],selectedStatesId);
     [selectedState addObject:text];
     [selectedStatesId addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexings]];
     [selectedStatesForSelect2 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexings]];
     NSLog(@"select%@count%lu",selectedStatesForSelect2,(unsigned long)[selectedState count]);
     if([selectedState count] > 3){

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hold On..." message:@"You can't select more than three states." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [selectedState removeObject:text];
            [selectedStatesId removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexings]];
        }

 }
}
```

[image]

That seen like this. When user select first time it works very good. But after closing the table view, when user again open the state list I want to show the previous selected item. Thats not working properly. I'm using a library for check "CRMultiRowSelector".Please help me.

Comment: Udai kumar try my coding.It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give what you ask.I tried many times this.It works perfectly

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewCheckMarkPreviousSelectionUpdate;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
   NSMutableArray *arrProductSelection,*arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark;
   NSArray *arrayFetchFromDefaults;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tableViewCheckMarkPreviousSelectionUpdate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   arrProductSelection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"iPhone",@"iPad",@"iPod",@"iTV",@"iWatch",@"iMac",nil];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  arrayFetchFromDefaults = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"selectedcheckmark"];
  arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayFetchFromDefaults];
  if(arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark.count == 0)
  {
     arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     for(int j=0;j<[arrProductSelection count];j++)
     {
        [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark addObject:@"deselected"];
     }
   }
   [tableViewCheckMarkPreviousSelectionUpdate reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return arrProductSelection.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *strCell = @"cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
   if(cell==nil)
   {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
   }
   if([[arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"deselected"])
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   else
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   cell.textLabel.text = [arrProductSelection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate Methods
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    @try
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [cell convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableViewCheckMarkSelectionUpdate];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableViewCheckMarkSelectionUpdate indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
        NSLog(@"%@",arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark);
        if([arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark count]==0)
        {
           for(int i=0; i<[arrProductSelection count]; i++)
           {
             [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark addObject:@"deselected"];
           }
        }
        if([[arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"deselected"])
        {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
           [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"selected"];
        }
        else
        {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
           [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"deselected"];
        }

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark forKey:@"selectedcheckmark"];
        [defaults synchronize];
      }
   @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"The exception is-%@",exception);
   }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save indexPaths and while creating the cell you have to again reassign state of cell. If it is selected or not.

In

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{}
```

in this method keep selected indexPaths and check for same indexPaths in `cellPathForRowIndexPath`, if there there show as checked otherwise unchecked.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I did this thing and it show the correct answer but when i scroll the table view its layout get distorted. After deselecting the previous again not selecting.

Comment: probably after getting dequeued cell you need to set the data again. When you scroll tableView Cell dequeue when you gets the this cell that will be plain content view cell. Nothing will be there, you need redraw everything again.